# How can I use @WebMvcTest for a Controller that uses an autowired ConversionService?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-mvc-test

In a Spring Boot application, I have two POJOs, `Foo` and `Bar`, and a `BarToFooConverter`, which looks like:

```
@Component
public class BarToFooConverter implements Converter<Bar, Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo convert(Bar bar) {
        return new Foo(bar.getBar());
    }
}
```

I also have a controller which makes use of the converter:

```
@RestController("test")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public Foo put(@RequestBody Bar bar) {
        return conversionService.convert(bar, Foo.class);
    }
}
```

I'd like to test this controller with `@WebMvcTest`, something like:

```
@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                put("/test")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("{\"bar\":\"test\"}"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

but when I run this, I find that my `BarToFooConverter` was not registered with the `ConversionService`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.example.demo.web.Bar] to type [com.example.demo.web.Foo]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:324)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:187)
    at com.example.demo.web.TestController.put(TestController.java:15)
```

This seems to make sense, because, according to [the Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html):

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).

However, the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) differs slightly, saying that `@WebMvcTest` *does* include `Converter`s:

> @WebMvcTest auto-configures the Spring MVC infrastructure and limits scanned beans to @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter, GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer, and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. Regular @Component beans are not scanned when using this annotation.

It seems that the reference guide is incorrect here - or am I registering my `Converter` incorrectly?

I have also tried mocking the `ConversionService` in my test with:

```
@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        when(conversionService.convert(any(Bar.class), eq(Foo.class))).thenReturn(new Foo("test"));

        mockMvc.perform(
                put("/test")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("{\"bar\":\"test\"}"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

but now Spring complains that my mock `ConversionService` is overriding the default one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService called as a bean reference for type [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$da4e303a]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:402)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    ...
```

Ideally I'd like to use my original approach, with the real Converter in my test rather than mocking the `ConversionService`, but with `@WebMvcTest` to limit the scope of the components that are started, so I also tried using an `includeFilter` in the `@WebMvcTest` annotation:

```
@WebMvcTest(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.example.demo.web.Bar*"))
```

but it still fails with the original 'No converter found capable of converting...' error message.

This feels like something that must be quite a common requirement - what am I missing?

Comment: I don't have time to investigate this any more thoroughly now, but just as a mention for people finding this - there seems to be a difference in the Spring version - I upgraded the version of Spring Boot a few weeks ago and found that tests started failing. I can't remember why now, but think it was that the real `ConversionService` was now being injected, when it hadn't been previously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register your converter manually in `@Before` annotated method. All you have to do is to inject [`GenericConversionService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService.html) and call [`addConverter(new BarToFooConverter())`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService.html#addConverter-org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter-) to make the converter resolvable. In this case you can get rid of mocking part. Your test could look like this:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.put;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private GenericConversionService conversionService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        conversionService.addConverter(new BarToFooConverter());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                put("/test")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("{\"bar\":\"test\"}"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Alternative solution: Spring Boot since version **1.4.0** provides a [collection of test-related auto-configurations](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4#auto-configuration-customizations) and one of these auto-configurations is [`@AutoConfigureMockMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/AutoConfigureMockMvc.html) that configures `MockMvc` component that works fine with injected converter components.